# getFromLocationName() can't find streets in Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I have this method that get's the street names for Ambassy's out of a XML file and shows them on the map.

This is the method that I'm using:

```
locatie = gc.getFromLocationName(gevondenland.getAdresamba(),5);
```

and I open an MapActivity with the location (locatie) i get.

This does work, but only for some countries.

Here is a sample from the XML file:

```
<land>
   <naam>Angola</naam>
   <code>AO</code>
   <politie>110</politie>
   <ambulance>118</ambulance>
   <brandweer>118</brandweer>
   <telamba>00244222310686</telamba>
   <adresamba>Edificio Secil, Avenida 4 de Fevereiro 42-6� en 10�, Luanda</adresamba>
</land>
<land>
   <naam>Antigua en Barbuda</naam>
   <code>AG</code>
   <politie>911</politie>
   <ambulance>911</ambulance>
   <brandweer>911</brandweer>
   <telamba>0012684811857</telamba>
   <adresamba>High Street, Sint John�s, Antigua</adresamba>
</land>
<land>
   <naam>Argentini�</naam>
   <code>AR</code>
   <politie>101</politie>
   <ambulance>107</ambulance>
   <brandweer>100</brandweer>
   <telamba>00541143380050</telamba>
   <adresamba>Edificio Porte�o II, Olga Cossettini 831, piso 3, Buenos Aires</adresamba>
</land>
```

Antigua en Barbuda works, but Argentinia and Angola don't.

When I search the exact same address on Google Maps, it finds it.

What can be the reason it can't find the addresses in Android?

Comment: Any error messages?  Return codes?  Log?

Comment: I get an NullPointerException when I want to show it on the map, which is quite logical as I don't get a Location (0 found).
The problem is why it doesn't find a location, while it DOES found one on maps.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first address line (Angola) I **don't** get a loaction on google maps. I had to remove *Edificio Secil,* and the street numbers from the string to get an result.

To me, the problem is not related to countries but to the content of the adress strings.

Comment: Hmm you are right.

Is there a way I can avoid this? Because I don't want to look up and rename 150+ entities..

Comment: Well it doesn't find "Shahr-e Naw, Kabul" in my app, while it DOES find it in Google Maps?

Comment: Here it is:

<land>
   <naam>Afghanistan</naam>
   <code>AF</code>
   <politie>100</politie>
   <ambulance>102</ambulance>
   <brandweer>112</brandweer>
   <telamba>0093700286641</telamba>
   <adresamba>Shahr-e Naw , Kabul</adresamba>
</land>